# Spring data neo4j fails to connect to neo4j 2.2.1

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have install the latest neo4j version on my new server, and now I can not connect to the server via spring data neo4j.
Getting this error:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON ''
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
    ... 170 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON ''
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.jsonToSingleValue(JsonHelper.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toEntity(RequestResult.java:114)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toMap(RequestResult.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.batch.CypherResult.<init>(CypherResult.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:548)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:568)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:235)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
```

the issue seems to be with Jackson:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2768)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2711)
```

I have tried to upgrade to the latest driver 2.2.1 but it did not helped.
the versions I user are:

```
<neo4j.version>2.2.1</neo4j.version>
<spring-data-neo4j>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j>
<spring-data-commons>1.9.1.RELEASE</spring-data-commons>
```

is there a way to make it work with the newly released neo4j server?

Answer (score 0):

You should use at least SDN 3.3.0.RELEASE for this, it should work with Server but it won't work with embedded.

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error
neo4j.version is 2.2.1, 
spring-data-neo4j 3.3.0.RELEASE and spring-data-commons is 1.10.0.RELEASE

Comment: I got the same error... It was working pretty fine with Neo4J 2.1.6 and SDN 3.0.5 (which is old I know..) and got this issue.. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think I encountered similar issue, I have been told SDN 3.3.0.RELEASE is not compatible with Neo4J 2.2.1. You need to wait for SDN 4.0, and there is a migration manual in writing progress here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/html/#migration

Comment: You can try 4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version, development in progress. But you'll need to migrate your code and NOT sure it would work.

Comment: And here official answer from Neo4j : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30323760/1349585